# Skyrim console command to set undiscovered location as discovered

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a console command in Skyrim Elder Scrolls V to set an undiscovered location as discovered so I can fast travel to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are 2 ways to do it.**

First way is to run the command `tmm 1` which enables all the map markers, which allows you to fast travel to anywhere you want.

The second way is like a workaround for this. You might not want to enable all the markers, so just teleporting there might be what you want. The command for that is `coc [the town you are teleporting to]`.

Comment: [Obligatory Photoshop](https://gyazo.com/6d1a63d6e7d3faab8b2ee99570c48461)